# Better way to return a list of items that meet certain conditions instead of +=

Tags: python-2.7, formatting, converters

and excuse my ignorance but I'm new to python.
I'm trying to mod a converter in python 2.7 and I find it extremely difficult to make some functions work as I like, so any help will be greatly appreciated.
I have these specific parts of code.

```
    def int2hex(self, int):
    return ("%x" % int)

    def Caids(self):
    caids = ""
    service = self.source.service
    if service:
        info = service and service.info()
        if info:
            caids = list(set(info.getInfoObject(iServiceInformation.sCAIDs)))
    return caids


def CaidList(self):
    caids = self.Caids()
    caidlist = ""
    if caids:
        for caid in caids:
            caid = self.int2hex(caid).upper().zfill(4)
            if (len(caids) > 1):
                caidlist = ", ".join("{:04x}".format(x) for x in caids).upper()
            else:
                caidlist += caid
    return caidlist
```

In the above code I have managed to create a hex list string which includes certain elements (the caids) with list(set(info.getInfoObject(iServiceInformation.sCAIDs))) and remove duplicates. Then I take each caid, convert it to hex and return a new caidlist with the same elements separated with a comma and spaces. Up to here everything is fine. The result is a list of hex numbers such as 0500, 0502, 0100, 0D07 etc.
The problem stars when I want to convert each caid to a Text element by meeting certain criteria.

I made this code that follows the previous one:

```
def CaidTxtList(self):
    caids = self.Caids()
    caidtxt = ""

    if caids:
        for caid in caids:
            caid = self.int2hex(caid).upper().zfill(4)
            if str(caid).startswith("01"):
                caid = "Seca"
            if str(caid).startswith("05"):
                caid = "Viaccess"
            if str(caid).startswith("06"):
                caid = "Irdeto"
            if str(caid).startswith("0D"):
                caid = "CryptoWorks"
            caidtxt += caid
            caidtxt += " "
    return caidtxt
```

In the above code I managed to transform each caid to an equivalent text. The result is a string of words that corresponds to each hex caid but I haven't managed to get the structure I have with the join command like their hex equivalents, just like in the CaidList part.

With caidtxt += caid what I get is Viaccess, Viaccess, Seca, CryptoWorks, (whitespace).

What I try to achieve is:

1. return a string with the texts where each caid is replaced by the equivalent text. This is already done but I want to change the formatting.
2. Remove the duplicate entries and the extra whitespace in the end. In Viaccess, Viacess, Seca, Cryptoworks how can I make Viaccess appear only once and remove trailing whitespace?
   I tried join and set but each time I either have a concatenate error (set and str) or the string has mixed up letters.
3. In short what is done in the CaidList part I want to be done in CaidTxtList part with words not duplicated.

I know I'm close and I feel stupid for not knowing how to move further. I have seen many documentations and examples but everything I've tried has failed miserably. So if there is any way to achieve the formatting I like, please help me!

Comment: I'd like to help, but I'm having a difficult time reproducing your results by mocking inputs and outputs.. replacing `caids = self.Caids()` with your example list `caids = [0x1811, 0x0500, 0x0D07]` prints `1811 Viaccess 0D07`, but this doesn't seem useful. Any idea how we can reproduce your results?

Comment: The first command caids = list(set(info.getInfoObject(iServiceInformation.sCAIDs))) what it does is it reads the caids of an encrypted satellite channel, puts them in a list and removes duplicates. These caids are in a decimal numerical form. For instance if the service has three different caids (let's say Viaccess, Seca, Nagravision) the string will be 1280 256 3479. This is what self.Caids() does. Now I want this list in hex without 0x. So I use def int2hex which converts each caid in the list to the equivalents 0500 0100 0D97. In the def CaidList() function I convert that to what I like.

Comment: which is the desired format 0500, 0100, 0D97. This is fine.Things get complicated if I want to repeat the function, but instead of 0500, 0100, 0D97 to come up with the text string Viaccess, Seca, Nagravision. With the += command I do this but the formatting is not what I want it returns Seca, Viaccess, Nagravision, (whitespace). The equivalents are transformed with the if part of the code. The startswith("05") will convert everything starting with 05 to Viaccess and so on. But if I have two caids starting with 05 it will bring up Viaccess twice. I want to uniquefy this.

Comment: I tried join and set but I failed. With set the letters appear mixed up. With join I cannot return the caids at all, because I do not know how to create the caidlist in order to enter it in the join function.

Comment: thank you for your further explanation, but is there possibly anyway you can create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: OK, I'll try to mock the input as well with an example. caids = [0500, 0502, 0100, 0D97]
    caidtxt = ""
    if caids:
        for caid in caids:
            if str(caid).startswith("01"):
                caid = "Seca"
            if str(caid).startswith("05"):
                caid = "Viaccess"
            if str(caid).startswith("0D"):
                caid = "Nagravision"

            caidtxt += caid
            caidtxt += " "

    return caidtxt

Comment: This will print Viaccess, Viaccess, Seca, Nagravision, (whitespace). I can get up to that point but I don't like this formatting. Instead I want with this input to print Viaccess, Seca, Nagravision without the last comma and the whitespace. Instead of the results produced with += to use another command that will uniquefy each caid with the same criteria and remove the trailing comma and whitespace.

Comment: And thank you so much for helping me, needless to say! :)

Comment: Thanks for providing more example, but that code with input gives me `Viaccess 0502 Seca 0D97` with no comma `,`

Comment: please edit your question and add all the information and code you put here in the comments.It's diffcult to read with so many additional things in the comment. And pls. also fix the indentation error in your code.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question hoping I explain this better. I also hope I fixed indentation errors, I don't have these in my code, perhaps something got messed during the paste.

Comment: Thank you to everyone for their help. I managed to get the formatting I wanted. What I was missing is that the initial input was a string, not a list. So I converted the string to list and took it from there. Sometimes the simplest things can be below your nose!